# Jacoco Report Aggregation Plugin - Spring Dependency Management

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, dependency-management, jacoco, gradle-plugin

I’m doing a migration of aggregated code coverage from script [Reporting code coverage with JaCoCo Sample](https://docs.gradle.org/6.5/samples/sample_jvm_multi_project_with_code_coverage.html?_ga=2.139033659.925057177.1662967461-1230651588.1601997347) to [The JaCoCo Report Aggregation Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jacoco_report_aggregation_plugin.html?_ga=2.150371390.925057177.1662967461-1230651588.1601997347)
This is a SpringBoot project and as it’s or it was a common practice, it uses [Dependency Management Plugin](https://docs.spring.io/dependency-management-plugin/docs/current/reference/html/).

After I run testCodeCoverageReport task to aggregate test reports I get following exceptions. I assume this is because I use BOM and dependency version constraint from within dependencyManagement instead of native Gradle dependency constraints.
Exception below:

Execution failed for task ':testCodeCoverageReport'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':allCodeCoverageReportClassDirectories'.
> Could not find com.pizza.infrastructure:logging:.
> Required by:
> project : > project :pizza-server
> Could not find com.pizza.infrastructure:multitenancy:.
> Required by:
> project : > project :pizza-server
> Could not find com.pizza.infrastructure:rest:.
> Required by:
> project : > project :pizza-server
> project : > project :pizza-server > project :pizza-rest
> Could not find com.pizza.infrastructure:rest-test:.
> Required by:
> project : > project :pizza-server

Is there a solution, to be able to still rely on dependencyManagement plugin and also be able to use jacoco aggregation plugin?

Comment: I had the same problem. The workaround I found was to specify dependency versions everywhere.  :^\

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not ideal, but I have the following plugin block in my build.gradle.kts for my 'test-results' module to resolve spring related dependencies, by adding the last two gradle plugins

```
plugins {
    id("jacoco-report-aggregation")
    id("test-report-aggregation")
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.6.6"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.11.RELEASE"
}
```